# In macOS, are there settings/apps that would 'grab my attention' when battery is running out?

Tags: macos, battery

I have been Windows user all my life, just got MacBook Pro through company. I use multiple external monitors and often get deeply buried into one of them.

What's annoying is whenever the battery is about to die, Mac sends a 'silent notification' at top right corner on the main screen (i.e. laptop's screen) and I totally miss it and battery dies down, it goes into sleep and that's when I realize battery was dead.

So the question, **are there any settings/app that will sound/alarm/pop-up/freeze etc to tell me battery is dying?**

Version:
MacBook Pro 2019
OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Why aren’t you charging your Mac while you use the monitors?

Comment: The top menu can be put on the main screen or any of the monitors in use and the battery status shown using system preferences.

Comment: Yes, If you're plugged in to two monitors, you're not going anywhere, so you might as well just leave it plugged in.

Comment: of course I plugin my laptop, but from time to time, I use the charger for other stuff iPad, iPhone and other mac laptop. I need to buy more of these for other devices, however for the situation I'm in, all I need is good alert system.